# CP / Backend: Restrict single entry only to admins (edit / delete)

Tags: control-panel, entry

I'm searching for an idea, to protect a single entry from being edited / deleted by editors (CP / backend).
Of course, it's easy to do for fields or sections, but for a single entry ... hmmm ...

- https://plugins.craftcms.com/isolate?craft4 -> that's not fitting to my needs
- a concept could be, to manipulate the CP with CSS / JS -> looks like a dirty hack
- maybe a custom plugin is needed -> a problem for me, unfortunalety

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Making the one entry it's own section is not an option? If not, all I could think of is a CP plug in with a hook ...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single for that entry. When you add a new single, existing users have no access by default.

Additionally, if your page must live within a structure, you can create a new page type (e.g. 'Linked entry') with a field that can select only one entry from 'singles'. In the template for your new page type takes the input from that field and use it to create a [redirect](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/tags.html#redirect) to your single; which editors do not have permission to edit/delete.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, Seth!

But that's not working: In my case, it's a subentry inside a structure ... concrete a specific subpage of the sitemap.

But I want to be sure, that this subpage will not be deleted by mistake by any editor.

Comment: Does it really have to be in a structure though? You could set up the single URL to appear as though it belonged in the structure; and was included in the site map accordingly. E.g: /about/press-releases/not-really-a-press-release could just be a single; an uneditable one-off

Comment: Yes ... because the editors are free to add / edit / remove subpages of this entry. I just want to protect this parent entry, because this entry id and position in the pagetree is important. It's a kind of "folder" ... not a page.

Comment: The concept to remove functionality in control panel with css / js is not too bad ... but it still is a dirty workaround and I'm missing a state of the art concept for this usecase in Craft.

Answer (score 0):

Without using singles, you'll need to write a module to add this functionality.

I'd recommend adding a new field to the section called "User Allow List" (or "Deny List" you can go either way with this).

Add an on-event function that checks the users in this field and sends a 403 if the current user does not match.

Add an on-save function for entries in this section that auto-populates your default list of Users. Now that I've typed this far.... best to do this by User Group and not individual Users. Have the field be a dropdown and not a User selection field, have the values match the ID or slug of the user group and check against that group.

Then you can add/remove users from that access list to manage it.

(you could also browse the plugin marketplace, I havent looked but maybe someone has published something like this already)

Comment: Ok, thx for you comment, Cherry!

This'll be my challenge to write my first module ... but you gave me a concept at least. :)

Comment: Best of luck! You'll feel great once you do one ^_^